# My jqGrid is not loading any icons (edit/add/search etc.)

Tags: css, jqgrid, icons

The Grid Loads but the icons for Add/Edit/Search etc. do not appear. When I hover over the place where the icons are supposed to be, I can see the names for the icons (but the icons do not show up).
Does anyone have similar problem?
Please help.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery2.0.2.min.js", 
     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js",
     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", 
     "~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
     "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js",
     "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" ));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( 
     "~/Content/themes/Style.css",           
     "~/Content/jqGrid/jquery-ui-jqgrid.css",    
     "~/Content/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" )); 

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

function LoadAllUsers()
{
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: privateserviceURL + "LoadAllUsers",

        datatype: 'json',
        //url access method type
        mtype: 'POST',
        //columns names
        colNames: ['UserId', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Password', 'Phone'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', width: 55 },
            { name: 'First Name', index: 'FirstName', width: 90 },
            { name: 'Last Name', index: 'LastName', width: 90 },
            { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Password', index: 'Password', width: 90 },
            { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 90 },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'UserId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "JSON Example"
    }).navGrid('#pager2', { edit: true, add: true, del: false });    

}
```

Comment: Thanks Chad for your prompt reply. This is how my bundle file looks like. I am pretty sure I have the buttons here.        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                            "~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
                             "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js",

Comment: "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"                             
                            ));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                            "~/Content/themes/Style.css",
                            "~/Content/jqGrid/jquery-ui-jqgrid.css", "~/Content/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"
                            ));
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Comment: Ok it seems the jquery ui icons are not displaying even though I have loaded all the required and js and css files..